# Exercise 7, Section 6.6 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, projection

> Prove that if $E$ is the projection on $R$ along $N$, then $(I-E)$ is the projection on $N$ along $R$.

**My attempt:** Suppose $E:V\to V$ is projection on $R$ along $N$. By [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4626550/861687), $R_E=R$ and $N_E=N$. Let $\alpha \in V$. Then $$(I-E)^2(\alpha)=(I-E)(\alpha -E(\alpha))=\alpha -E(\alpha)-E(\alpha)+E^2(\alpha)=\alpha -E(\alpha)=(I-E)(\alpha).$$ So $(I-E)(\alpha )=(I-E)^2(\alpha)$, $\forall \alpha \in V$. Thus $(I-E)$ is a projection. We need to show $R_{I-E}=N=N_E$ and $N_{I-E}=R=R_E$. Let $x\in R_{I-E}$. Since $I-E$ is a projection, $(I-E)(x)=x-E(x)=x$. So $E(x)=0$ and $x\in N_E$. Thus $R_{I-E}\subseteq N_E$. Let $x\in N_E$. Then $E(x)=0$. By elementary property of $V$, we have $x-E(x)=x=(I-E)(x)$. So $x\in R_{I-E}$. Thus $R_{I-E}\supseteq N_E$. Hence $R_{I-E}= N_E$. Let $x\in N_{I-E}$. Then $(I-E)(x)=0$. So $E(x)=x$. Thus $x\in R_E$ and $N_{I-E}\subseteq R_E$. Let $x\in R_E$. Since $E$ is a projection, $E(x)=x$. So $(I-E)(x)=0$. Thus $x\in N_{I-E}$ and $N_{I-E}\supseteq R_E$. Hence $R_{I-E}= N_E$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Your proof is fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $V=R\oplus N$. By definition we have $Ev_R=v_R, Ev_n=0$ for all $v_r\in R$ and $v_n\in N$. Therefore,

$$(I-E)v_R=v_R-v_R=0, \quad (I-E)v_N=v_N-0=v_N$$

Moreover,

$$(I-E)^2=I-2E+E^2=I-E$$

Hence $I-E$ is the projection on $N$ along $R$.

Comment: Your solution is so slick.

Comment: It took some time to absorb your proof. Construction (assigning basis vector) of $E$ in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4626550/861687) definition of projection on $R$ along $N$ is similar to construction of $(I-E)$….. I don’t know exactly how to phrase it.